# Same CSS/HTML different result?

Tags: html, css, space

I have a HTML file where I always use the same header (I include it at the top of every page)
I used CSS to style this header...

The overall body has no space on top, thats good.
Now I have space on top of the page in the index.php and no space at the top in the contact.php, althought it has the ***same header and exact the same CSS file*** linked enter code here to it...

How can that be?

(sorry for the bad code sample, but the website is to complex to show it...)

```css
.body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%;
 clear: both;
}
.mainHeader img{
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 display: block;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
//index file
<?php
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>

//contact file
<?php
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>

//header file
<html>
<head>
    <title>Website Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
<header class="mainHeader">
 <img src="logo.png"></img>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="#"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
     <li class="#"><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without looking at the actual source-files. Take a look in the developer console in whatever browser you're using, look at the applied paddings and margins, and the associated styles. Somewhere, there is something different.

Comment: Get rid of the `</img>`, image tags don't get closed.

Comment: Sorry I am not a PHP guy, but it seems odd that your header include has `html`,`head`,and `body` tags in it. I thought that includes were suppose to be like partial views. Also, don't get tunnel vision... the problem might not be with the header file or the header CSS, but could be the markup on the index.php page (like a stray character or invalid markup) or with that pages styles.

Comment: What does _index.php_ and _contact.php_ actually look like? It looks like you have some pseudo code above. Make sure you don't have any whitespace before the initial markup, i.e. something like `<?php (includes) ?> <html>` (space between `?> <html>`) vs `<?php (includes) ?></html>`. FWIW, I would include a doctype, i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as we don't see all the code from the included php files, we may only guess.
Talking about CSS, you may try to use a "Reset CSS" file in your project. Reset CSS is a css code that clears all margins, paddings and so on for the elements in your page. You could take a look here http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

And the code is here:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

So maybe give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but it doesn´t help me a lot... I found out that the problem is, that Chrome maks a user agent sylesheet on my body... It is wired, that it is just on some pages... do you have an idea how to deleat that user agent stylesheet on the body? Thank you... Marius